# Reactjs - How do I check to see if a user clicks a textbox within a table row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with rows with each row containing a textbox where some numbers can be typed in.

In addition, if a user clicks the table row, it expands to show sub fields within that row.

```
<tr className={this.props.showDetails === true ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'}
    onClick={() => this.props.showOrHideDetails(someArgument)}>
    <td className='col-md-2'>
         <Glyphicon className="arrow" glyph={this.props.showDetails === true ? 'triangle-bottom' : 'triangle-right'} />
         <input className="" type="text" placeholder="Type text"/>
     </td>
     ...
```

My problem is that if a user clicks within a textbox in order to type stuff, the `showOrHideDetails` is triggered thus expanding the row and showing the details.   Now, of course it makes sense based on the way the code is structured but how do I expand the row ONLY IF they haven't clicked into the textbox part?  I haven't quite figured that out yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can listen [Focus and Blur](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#focus-events) events for the input.

Comment: So basically what you want is the details to be shown not when you click the textbox, but instead once you start typing?

Comment: @Chris No, the row is expanded only when the user clicks on any part of the row other than the textbox.  If they click into the textbox, allow them to type into it.

Comment: @bennygenel will `onFocus/onBlur` events on the `input` tag take precedence over the `onClick` of the `tr` though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could prevent the event from propagating to the parent element. This will prevent `showOrHideDetails` from firing.

```
<input onClick={ e => { e.stopPropagation();} } className="" type="text" placeholder="Type text"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!